# Override next parameter django-social-auth to track facebook logins and new users in Google Analytics

Tags: django, google-analytics, django-socialauth

I have been working with django only for a few months and I am modifying now a django code base made by another developer.

I am trying to find a way to effectively track facebook registrations and logins in Google Analytics and a way I thought of doing this is by adding a parameter to the url the user is redirected after connecting through facebook.

At the moment we are using the 'next' parameter like this:

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
```

I want to be able to override the next param in order to add:

```
{{request.path}}?new_facebook_user
```

or

```
{{request.path}}?facebook_login
```

if the user was already registered.

Where do you think the best place of doing this is? Do you think this is a valid approach to track fb logins and new users in google analytics?

Answer (score 1):

That approach won't work, at least you won't be able to determine if the user is new or not when you create that link. The app provides the `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` setting to define a different URL to where redirect newly created accounts. This setting takes precedence over `?next=` parameter, so it will be lost if defined.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. I have been also checking the FB SDK which may also help. Still need to have a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method in your pipeline like this:

```
def modify_next(backend, is_new=True, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == "facebook":
        next = backend.strategy.session_get("next")
        if is_new:
            backend.strategy.session_set("next", "{}?new_facebook_user".format(next))
        else:
            backend.strategy.session_set("next", "{}?facebook_login".format(next))
```

So you will modify the default next behabiour.